# Replace "\/" with "/" in an array in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following array that contains lots of "\/", since the array is generated from a screen scrape of the javascript of a page "\/" is meant to be just "/". Here's the array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1 Jet Black 
    [1] => 1B\/350T Black With Copper Tips 
    [2] => 1B\/BGT Black With Burgandy Tips 
    [3] => 1b Natural Black 
    [4] => 2 Darkest Brown 
    [5] => 4 Chocolate Brown 
    [6] => 27 Strawberry Blonde 
)
```

The best I can think of would be to:

```
$a = array("1B\/BGT Black With Burgandy Tips", "1B\/350T Black With Copper Tips");

foreach ($a as $key => $itsvalue) {
    $a[$key] = strreplace("\\\/","\/",$itsvalue)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be :-

```
<?php
$a = array("1B\/BGT Black With Burgandy Tips", "1B\/350T Black With Copper Tips");

foreach ($a as $key => $itsvalue) {
    $a[$key] = str_replace("\/","/",$itsvalue)
}
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine:

```
$a = array("1B\/BGT Black With Burgandy Tips", "1B\/350T Black With Copper Tips");

foreach ($a as $key => $itsvalue) {
    $a[$key] = str_replace("\/","/", $itsvalue);
}

print_r($a);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => 1B/BGT Black With Burgandy Tips [1] => 1B/350T Black With Copper Tips )
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace can take an array for the subject and will run the replacement for each element in the array. Try:

```
$replacedArray = preg_replace('#\\\/#', '/', $array);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php